# Where is alloc_bootmem(...) in 5.11.0 Kernel source?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am looking for the code for alloc_bootmem(...) family of functions in Ubuntu source with 5.11.0-27 source.

I am not able to locate it. Wondering why I am not finding it. Could someone give me some pointers about what I am doing wrong.  I used it years ago while working on a graphics driver; but have not looked for it lately.  I notice, there are several references to it on the Internet; but all of them seem to be dated. I am tempted to say it has been refactored; but that does not seem likely.

Thank you for your time/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*bootmem.c* was removed in v4.20-rc1 with commit [355c45affca7](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=355c45affca7)(“mm: remove bootmem allocator”) https://lwn.net/Articles/764807/